# Left multiplication isometry?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras

If $G$ is a semi-simple Lie group and $g\in G$, then $G$ has a bi-invariant metric which is a Riemmanian metric.  My question is:

with respect to this metric does the left-translation map
\begin{equation}
h \mapsto g\cdot h
\end{equation}
define an isometry on $G$?

(I apologize in advance if this question is trivial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost tautological. "Bi-invariant" means the metric is invariant under both left and right translation. The resulting distance function satisfies, in particular,
$$d(gx,gy)=d(x,y)$$
Hence left translation is an isometry (as is right translation).

Comment: Good point, sorry about that.  And thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @CSA no problem.